# How can I return a custom reponse for a bean validation error under Open Liberty?

Tags: bean-validation, open-liberty

We are using `beanValidation-2.0` and `cdi-2.0` under Open Liberty 20.0.0.3.  This works fine in that Open Liberty returns a 400 Bad Request response containing the bean validation error message when a a bean validation error is detected.  I would like to update our application to instead return a custom response when Open Liberty detects a bean validation error.  Is there a way that I can somehow "intercept" the bean validation error (or the Open Liberty generated response) and return my own custom response?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when you get a validation error, a [`ConstraintViolationException`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/bean-validation/2.0/apidocs/javax/validation/constraintviolationexception) is thrown and you should be able to catch that and create your own response.

If you're using JAX-RS, you might want to do this by creating and registering an [`ExceptionMapper`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/restful-ws/2.1/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/ext/exceptionmapper) to handle this type of exception and turn it into a response. [There's an example here.](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-nd/8.5.5?topic=applications-defining-exception-mappers-resource-exceptions-errors)

Comment: Thanks Azquelt.  Your solution works like a charm.  I was able to create a custom exception mapper class implementing ExceptionMapper<ConstraintViolationException> that returns a custom response.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do this with a custom [MessageInterpolator](https://javadoc.io/doc/javax.validation/validation-api/latest/javax/validation/MessageInterpolator.html).
It can be specified via the `message-interpolator` element of validation.xml.

Comment: Thanks for the MessageInterpolator suggestion.  I'm not familiar with MessageInterpolator and plan to do my own searching; but I'd greatly appreciate any references/examples  on how a custom MessageInterpolator could be used to generate a custom response, especially in the context of Open Liberty, you (or anyone else) are aware of.